# Using SVN client on Git repo (not github)

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible to use an SVN client (e.g. Tortoise) on a Git repo? Please note that I'm not referring to the usual case (Git client on SVN) but the reverse (i.e. git-svn does **not** work).

We are migrating from SVN to Git but some of the team members do not want to do 3 steps to push something (stage,commit,push) but want the single step concept as well as they don't want to see all the branches in the logs etc. Is this possible?

Comment: ahhhhh.... not that I know of. Just tell them that it's a different tool with different workflows and that resisting it is just not the way to go forward... quite frankly, after a while of using git and taking advantage of its features not available in svn, they will be asking themselves how they made it so many years without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SVN can't tell with Git. But you can have bidirectional sync with SubGit in-between Git-repo and SVN-repo